# Vectorize for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have the following data:

```
Letters <- c("A","B","C")
Numbers <- c(1,0,1)
Numbers <- as.integer(Numbers)

Data.Frame <- data.frame(Letters,Numbers)
```

I want to create a Dummy Variable for the Letters and wrote the following for-loop:

```
for(level in unique(Data.Frame$Letters)){Data.Frame[paste("", level, sep = "")]
<- ifelse(Data.Frame$Letters == level, 1, 0)}
```

Is there a way to vectorize this for-loop? Is the following use of dcast alredy vectorized?

```
dt <- data.table(Letters,Numbers)
dcast.data.table(dt, Letters+Numbers~Letters,fun.aggregate=length)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `outer`

```
cbind(Data.Frame, +outer(Letters, setNames(nm=Letters), "=="))
#   Letters Numbers A B C
# 1       A       1 1 0 0
# 2       B       0 0 1 0
# 3       C       1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And this is vectorized because the outer function is applying "==" to the two vectors Letters and setNames(nm=Letters)?

Comment: `outer` is a vectorized function, yes.  (i.e. there are no internal loops)